# jQuery form validation with tinyMCE and nice tooltip / focus / error indication

Tags: jquery, validation, tinymce, tooltip

I try to use the [jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) together with [tinyMCE](http://archive.tinymce.com/index.php). What I would like to do is following:

- On submit the form shall be validated. Invalid controls shall be highlighted (with .error CSS class) and a tooltip shall inform about the error.
- Whenever the user fixes the error (e.g. by typing in the correct value), the tooltip and the .error highlight shall disappear.
- Whenever an error occurs, the first element in the form shall be focused.

The [tinyMCE / validation integration example](http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/tinymce/) already helped me a lot! But there is still an issue with updating the error state - especially for the tinyMCE form.

**I've prepared a running [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deb_ugger/z9wnrnso/).**

### Update

After some further investigation I found out, that in the "success" method, the "label" of the control (e.g. the textarea) is returned, not the control itself. See the console output. But I would need the control - any ideas how to do that? is that the correct approach how I do it?

Here is (only) the javascript (the whole example does not run here).

```js
/// jQuery Validator Defaults
$.validator.setDefaults({
  errorPlacement: function(error, obj) {
    console.log("invalid: id   - " + obj.attr('id'));
    console.log("invalid: type - " + obj.prop('nodeName'));

    var myobj = obj;
    if (obj.is("textarea")) {
      myobj = obj.prev().contents().find('iframe');
      obj.prev().addClass('error');
    }
    myobj.attr('title', error.text());
    var errorLocation = $(".error");
    errorLocation.tooltip({
      position: {
        my: "center bottom",
        at: "center top+8"
      }
    });
  },
  success: function(obj) {
    console.log("  valid: id   - " + obj.attr('id'));
    console.log("  valid: type - " + obj.prop('nodeName'));

    var myobj = obj;
    if (obj.is("textarea")) {
      myobj = obj.prev().contents().find('iframe');
      obj.prev().removeClass('error');
    }
    myobj.removeClass("error").attr("title", "");
  },
  focusInvalid: function(obj) {
    // put focus on tinymce on submit validation
    if (obj.settings.focusInvalid) {
      try {
        var toFocus = $(obj.findLastActive() || obj.errorList.length && obj.errorList[0].element || []);
        if (toFocus.is("textarea")) {
          tinyMCE.get(toFocus.attr("id")).focus();
        } else {
          toFocus.filter(":visible").focus();
        }
      } catch (e) {
        // ignore IE throwing errors when focusing hidden elements
      }
    }
  }
});

function initMCE() {
  $("textarea.tinymce").tinymce({
    theme: "modern",
    toolbar_items_size: "small",
    toolbar: "bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify table | copy paste | bullist numlist | undo redo | link fullscreen localautosave ",
    setup: function(editor) {
      editor.on("change", function(e) {
        //console.log("change event", e);
        tinyMCE.triggerSave();
        $("#" + editor.id).valid();
      });
    }
  });
}

$(function() {

  initMCE();

  var validator = $("#myform").submit(function() {
    // update underlying textarea before submit validation
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
  }).validate({
    ignore: "",
    rules: {
      title: "required",
      someoptions: "required",
      content: "required"
    },
    messages: {
      title: "Please enter title",
      someoptions: "Please choose option",
      content: "Please enter some text"
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some further trials and errors I did it :)

**Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deb_ugger/n2Ljbje7/).**

As you can see I now use the highlight and unhighlight method of the validation plugin:

```js
/// jQuery Validator Defaults
$.validator.setDefaults({
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    var myelement = element;

    if (element.is("textarea")) {
      myelement = element.prev().contents().find('iframe');
    }

    myelement.attr('title', error.text());
    var errorLocation = $(".error");
    errorLocation.tooltip({
      position: {
        my: "center bottom",
        at: "center top+8"
      }
    });
  },

  highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);

    if ($(element).is("textarea")) {
      $(element).prev().addClass('error');
    }
  },

  unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);

    if ($(element).is("textarea")) {
      $(element).prev().removeClass('error');
    }
  },

  success: function(element) {
    var myelement = element;
    if (element.is("textarea")) {
      myelement = element.prev().contents().find('iframe');
      //obj.prev().removeClass('error');
    }
    myelement.attr("title", "");
  }
});

function initMCE() {
  $("textarea.tinymce").tinymce({
    theme: "modern",
    toolbar_items_size: "small",
    toolbar: "bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify table | copy paste | bullist numlist | undo redo | link fullscreen localautosave ",
    setup: function(editor) {
      editor.on("change", function(e) {
        //console.log("change event", e);
        tinyMCE.triggerSave();
        $("#" + editor.id).valid();
      });
    }
  });
}

$(function() {

  initMCE();

  var validator = $("#myform").submit(function() {
    // update underlying textarea before submit validation
    tinyMCE.triggerSave();
  }).validate({
    debug: true,
    ignore: "",
    rules: {
      title: "required",
      someoptions: "required",
      content: "required"
    },
    messages: {
      title: "Please enter title",
      someoptions: "Please choose option",
      content: "Please enter some text"
    }
  });

  validator.focusInvalid = function() {
    // put focus on tinymce on submit validation
    if (this.settings.focusInvalid) {
      try {
        var toFocus = $(this.findLastActive() || this.errorList.length && this.errorList[0].element || []);
        if (toFocus.is("textarea")) {
          tinyMCE.get(toFocus.attr("id")).focus();
        } else {
          toFocus.filter(":visible").focus();
        }
      } catch (e) {
        // ignore IE throwing errors when focusing hidden elements
      }
    }
  }
});
```